# Solr Nested Documents: query for parent document which has several specific nested documents

Tags: indexing, solr

Let's imagine I have document with several nested documents:

```
{
  "id": "doc1",
  "type": "maindoc",
  "title": "some document 1 title"
  "nested": [
    {
      "id": "nested1",
      "nested_type": "nestedType1",
      "title": "nested doc 1 title"
    },
    {
      "id": "nested2",
      "nested_type": "nestedType2",
      "title": "nested doc 2 title"
    },
    {
      "id": "nested3",
      "nested_type": "nestedType3",
      "title": "nested doc 3 title"
    }
  ]
}
```

So now if I want to search for document which has nested doc 1 - I do this:

```
{!parent which='type:maindoc'}
nested_type:nestedType1
```

But what if I want to search for document which has 2 specific children at the same time?
For example I want to find doc which has both nestedType1 + nestedType2.

Obviously query like this will not work:

```
{!parent which='type:maindoc'}
nested_type:nestedType1 AND nested_type:nestedType2
```

So how can I do that? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this did the trick in my testing:

`({!parent which='type:maindoc' v='nested_type:nestedType1'}) AND ({!parent which='type:maindoc' v='nested_type:nestedType2'})`

Comment: For me it shows completely invalid results. So request
`{!parent which='type:maindoc'}nested_type:nestedType1` - shows valid results, but if I add brackets like this: `({!parent which='type:maindoc'}nested_type:nestedType1)` - it shows invalid results. Seems like it ignores child doc filter. So 2 filters with brackets with AND just show invalid results

Comment: @MikalaiUshanau Ah, the query parser was only applying to the first clause! This worked in my local code because of a property of my data set. I updated the query by putting the query inside the query parser `{}` with `v`. Does this work for you now?

Comment: Thank you! That helped. Obviously syntax is not soo nice, especially if we need to use a lot of conditions, but anyway it works!

Comment: It took me a while to become comfortable with this syntax, but I think this is the cleanest/most powerful way to write solr queries. `defType` has a very low ceiling which falls apart as soon as you need multiple query parsers affecting the same query. And working with nested documents unfortunately requires a lot of query parsers!